# Reutilizar un objeto en otra funcion, sin pasarlo como argumento

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos y perdón si no consigo explicarme bien.
Mi código es similar al que pego debajo. 
La funcion getRestaurants(allData) crea una tabla dinamica, iterando sobre el objeto "allData". 
Donde "allData" son distintos objetos que obtengo con llamadas a una API (es decir, que dependiendo de una función anterior, "allData" es un objeto u otro).
Y quiero conseguir , en la función goBack(), llamar de nuevo la funcion getRestaurants(allData) , para que se vuelva a generar la misma tabla.

En principio no es posible pasar el objeto como argumento de de goBack (no se podria hacer goBack(allData) ), porque crea otros problemas.

No se si queda claro, sino, decidme y veo si puedo mejorar el ejemplo

Ejemplo de codigo :

```
var allDataGlobal = {};
function getRestaurants(allData) {

 for (i = 0, i < allData.lenght, i++) {
     "genera una tabla dinamica con los datos del objeto"
allDataGlobal = allData;
console.log(allDataGlobal) //muestra el objeto correcto)
 }}

function goBack() {
console.log(allDataGlobal) // muestra el objeto vacio

 if ("caso A") {
     myFunction1();
 } if else {
     getrestaurants(allData);
 } else { otherFunction() }}
```

Añado la función fetch (el "cityId" varia segun el value de un Select anterior) :

```
function searchCity(cityId) {


  var url = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=" + cityId + "&entity_type=city";
  console.log(url);

  fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "user-key": "myKey"
      }

    })
    .then(function (res) {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      var allData = data.restaurants;

      getRestaurans(allData);

      console.log(allData[0].restaurant.location.address);

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
};
```

Comment: en que momento se ejecuta el goBack ?  como usar variables globales 
 talvez te da una idea https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: con la actualizacion parace ser que estas asignando un array en una variable de tipo objeto debes definir  var allDataGlobal = [];

Comment: @CarlosUmaña , cierto! no me habia dado cuenta, pero aun asi sigue apareciendo vacio  el segundo console.log(allDataGlobal)

Comment: @CarlosUmaña el goBack  se ejecuta con un boton en la página. Asi que se puede ejecutar en diversos momentos. Pero a traves de la if function , dependiendo de cuando se pulse, ejecuta una función u otra.

Comment: en tu funcion searchCity puedes asignar el valor a tu variable global
.then(function (data) {
      var allData = data.restaurants;
      allDataGlobal=allData;
      getRestaurans(allData);

      console.log(allData[0].restaurant.location.address);

    })

Comment: @CarlosUmaña ..en primer lugar gracias por seguir respondiendo.
Lo estoy haciendo asi, y eliminado cualquier otra referencia a allDataGlobal ...pero sigo recibiendo un "Undefined" ....joder..parece una tonteria pero..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te dijeron en los comentario, deberías almacenar los datos en una variable global una vez recibes la respuesta de la API, imaginando que haces la obtención de la información por medio de un AJAX el código sería algo así:

```
let allData;
let allDataGlobal;

$.ajax({
    url: "xxx",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(response){
        allData = response;
        allDataGlobal = allData;
        getRestaurants(allData); //Opcionalmente
    }
})

function getRestaurants(allData) {    
     for (i = 0, i < allData.lenght, i++) {
          "genera una tabla dinamica con los datos del objeto"
     }
}

function goBack() { //El siguiente código correría mejor con un switch y no con if anidados
     console.log(allDataGlobal);
     if ("caso A") {
         myFunction1();
     } else if {
         getrestaurants(allData);
     } else { 
          otherFunction()
     }
}
```

Comment: lo hago asi, pero cuando hago un console.log(allData) dentro de goBack() ....me da "Undefined" :/

Comment: En la edición de tu código veo que en getRestaurants() dentro del for 
 estás reasignando cada vez allDataGlobal, no lo hagas, solo llena esa variable dentro del fetch.

Comment: , Gracias. Lo modifiqué, pero sigo recibiendo "undefined" cuando lo alcanzo desde la funcion goBack.... :/

Comment: ¿Es posible que pongas el código en JSFiddle para que se pueda ver trabajando? Haz también el intento con alguna otra variable, debería funcionar bien, quizá hay algún momento donde estás reasignando la variable.

Comment: debe haber algo muy basico que estoy haciendo mal .... porque pruebo con otra variable cualquiera y pasa lo mismo. 
Si codePen te sirve, te lo agrego ahí

Comment: Sí, CodePen está bien.

Comment: https://codepen.io/wulfo/pen/dBXyWd

Comment: He editado mínimamente, prueba por favor  https://codepen.io/jonalxh/pen/orBMqx?editors=1111, he notado que estabas redeclarando las variables.

Comment: la unica edicion que encuentro es donde has declarado let allData;
let globalAllData; hay alguna mas?  
Porque me sigue dando "undefined" :/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95201/discussion-between-jonathan-arias-and-notadevyet).

Comment: Funciono! muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Simple como:

```
async function searchByCityId(cityId){
    try{
        let response = await (await fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: { "user-key": "myKey" } })).json(),
            restaurants = getRestaurants(response); 
            sessionStorage.setItem("currentRestaurantList", JSON.stringify(restaurants));
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
function getRestaurants(jsonResponse){
    //Procesar respuesta JSON
}

//Para leerlo en otro ámbito seria 
var restaurants = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentRestaurantList'))
```

Comment: mmm....tengo que probar, pero aun no he llegado a "estudiar" las async Functions en JS (empecé a estudiar JS hace unas 4 semanas). 
Preferia ver si es posible hacerlo con vanilla JS (a lo mejor las async son parte de vanilla JS ...no quiero meter la pata)

Comment: Son parte del ES6 y puedes ver la disponibilidad [aquí](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions)

Comment: gracias por la ayuda y el link!